# Strategy to build test graphs for Dijkstra's algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, dijkstra

I recently implemented Dijkstra's algorithm to practice Java. I'm now considering how to build random test graphs (with unidirectional edges).

Currently, I use a naive method. Nodes are created at random locations in 2d space (where x and y are unsigned integers between 0 and some MAX_SPACE constant). Edges are randomly created to connect the nodes, so that each node has an outdegree of at least 1 (and at most MAX_DEGREE). Indegree is not enforced. Then I search for a path between the first and last Nodes in the set, which may or may not be connected.

In a more realistic situation, nodes would have a probability of being connected proportional to their proximity in 2d space. What is a good strategy to build random test graphs with that property?

**NOTES**

I will primarily use this to build graphs that can be drawn and verified by hand, but scaling to larger graphs is a consideration.

The strategy should be easily modified to support the following constants (and maybe others -- let me know if you think of any interesting ones):

- MIN_NODES, MAX_NODES: a range of sizes for the graph
- CONNECTEDNESS: average out-degree
- PROXIMITY: weight given to preferring to connect proximal nodes

Comment: Maybe [GTgraph](http://www.cse.psu.edu/~madduri/software/GTgraph/index.html) tool can be helpful for you. It is being used for graph generation at shortest path challenges. Also I have found [this](http://videolectures.net/ecmlpkdd09_akoglu_rtg/) video.

Comment: @MadChuckle: Those both look like promising leads. Thank you!

Comment: @amit: Yes, since clusters are a feature of many real-world situations. But I don't expect any answer to contain *all* features.

Answer (score 2):

You could start by looking at the different random graph generators available in [JUNG](https://github.com/jrtom/jung) (Java library):

- [Barabasi Albert Generator](https://github.com/jrtom/jung/blob/master/jung-algorithms/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/jung/algorithms/generators/random/BarabasiAlbertGenerator.java) - Simple evolving scale-free random graph generator. At each time step, a new vertex is created and is connected to existing vertices according to the principle of "preferential attachment", whereby vertices with higher degree have a higher probability of being selected for attachment.
- [Eppstein Power Law Generator](https://github.com/jrtom/jung/blob/master/jung-algorithms/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/jung/algorithms/generators/random/EppsteinPowerLawGenerator.java) - Graph generator that generates undirected graphs with power-law degree distributions.

There are various other generators available to - [See Listing Here](https://github.com/jrtom/jung/blob/master/jung-algorithms/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/jung/algorithms/generators/random)

For python there is the [NetworkX](https://github.com/networkx/networkx) library that also provides many graph generators - [Listed Here](http://networkx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/generators.html)

With many of these generators you can specify the size, so you can start small and go from there.

Comment: All the links on this are broken.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know @SimonFeatherstone. Should all be fixed now.